# Movie about a photographer who takes pictures of weddings (or birthdays) and murders, who falls in love with a girl in his building

Tags: identify-this-movie

### *Technical* details

I am not really good at judging the age of a movie but I think it has been released between 2005 and 2014. It looked *modern*.

I think it's considered to be a drama, but it is very dark and stressful.

I watched it in English but I can't say if it was translated or not.

### The plot (spoilers)

It's the story of a ~30 years old man. He is a photographer and gets paid to take photos in weddings or birthdays (I can't remember) and on crime scenes.

During the movie it's a bit hard to know what really happens and what he imagines happening. For example, he sees two men in a bus bothering a woman and he imagines that he helps her. He walks up to them and they draw a gun but he manages to take the gun from them and the girl falls in love with him. But then he "wakes up" and realizes it was just a dream.

Then he meets a girl in his building and they have sex. He falls in love with her, but her ... Not so much.

During a wedding/birthday where he is taking pictures he notices that the father is cheating on his wife. So he follows him and takes pictures showing the father cheating. He then takes the father's watch in exchange for the pictures. He sells the watch and with the money he buys a ring for the girl he is in love with.

But he realizes that she has a new boyfriend. He follows the boyfriend to his apartment to scare him (not sure about this). And he ends up shooting him by accident. He tries to take him to the hospital but doesn't manage to do so in time. He then pretends a homeless man killed the boyfriend. And it ends on him taking pictures of the murder.

### Random parts of the story I can't put together

At one point he is watching a play made by the girl's friends and he hates it. He says something mean loud without meaning to and the girl gets mad at him.

Somewhere near the end we see the girl leaving him and she looks really sad and disappointed. But we then see the same scene multiple times and each time she looks happier. It's like he is changing his memories to convince himself that she isn't mad at him.

Thank you for helping me. I hope there is enough information.

Comment: As a member of this community I'd like to express my appreciation for how well done this question is. We may not be able to help (though hopefully we can) but you have certainly done everything you can to make our job easier! Thanks for your effort! I only hope that all ID questions could be done so well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Crave](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535432/combined) from 2012 with Ron Perlman and    Edward Furlong.

> Aiden (Josh Lawson) is an underpaid and lonely freelance crime scene photographer that copes with the world around him by imagining himself as a hero that saves the day. His world is turned upside down when he meets Virginia (Emma Lung), who breathes new life into his daily routine and gives him a new sense of confidence.

As Catija already said, a very detailed and thorough question. Here's the trailer: